# Sencha Example - "device" shows white screen on native android package

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

I tried using "device" example present at location "~\sencha-touch-2.0.1.1\examples\device" .
Now when I run it through browser it runs and I m able to see the "Device Orientation" and "Geolocation" module working as Camera module will only work when we convert to native build.

But when I convert the same to native android package and run that APk file on Nexus 7 tablet , I get a white screen with no errors on the "log" console.

Any ideas why is this not working?

Comment: i had also faced same problem once. I resolve it by giving all the necessary sencha set-up files inside "sdk" folder,after that APK file works properly. can u show your directory structure here. May be then i can help.

Comment: @Vikal:- Well you can see my entire code at https://github.com/adityap-optimus/Sencha-Touch-Phonegap/tree/master/DeviceAPI

Answer (score 0):

Need more information are you using index.html as your entry point??? give an alert there and see what happens

Comment: I tried that but still it didn't worked!! I mean i got no pop up/alert which i can see in the browser.

Comment: first line in index.html just give alert('something') if nothing comes then something is very wrong with your packaging... try giving it last line also if you dont get two alerts then there is an error in some js file you are trying to include

Comment: :- Firstly if i build that same app using phone gap it is build successfully and works like the same way in browser.. the problem occursd when i build using sencha SDK   here is the code which I m using https://github.com/adityap-optimus/Sencha-Touch-Phonegap/tree/master/DeviceAPI